# PDF text has strange mark at end of line of text

Tags: fonts, pdf, svg, corel-draw

I have artwork that has a strange mark at the end of each line of text.

This artwork is originally an SVG that was converted to a PDF using cairosvg, then opened with CorelDraw and put into production.

The mark is not normally visible in the SVG, a PDF viewer, or CorelDraw. It is visible in wireframe mode, and is visible on the produced product. It occurs on all of my artowrk files and occurs with any font.

Below is an image of it in CorelDraw wireframe, and a text element svg.

[image]

```
<g transform="translate(181.2 140)">
  <text font-family="Century Gothic" font-size="72" font-weight="bold" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: #000000; fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(-116.03 54)">
    <tspan x="0" y="-36" fill="#000000">TAFARI</tspan>
  </text>
</g>
```

What is causing this unwanted mark?

**UPDATE:**

I tested this extremely simple svg file and got the same result, so it seems the contents of the SVG makes no difference.

```
<svg height="30" width="200">
  <text x="0" y="15" fill="red">I love SVG!</text>
</svg>
```

**Update:**

This mark is specific to CorelDraw. Does not appear in Illustrator or other programs. Saving the PDF in Illustrator as a PDF and then opening the PDF in CorelDraw causes the mark to disappear, but this is not practical for my process.

Comment: Hi Goose, I tested the code in Illustrator and the marking doesn't show up in outline mode. So this is might be Corel Draw specific, not sure if you knew that or not. My guess is that line could indicate a paragraph break.

Comment: I actually did, should have noted that. Not sure where a paragraph break could be coming from.

Comment: Is it selectable and deletable in CorelDraw?

Comment: Yes. Text line comes in as one grouped object, but after break apart, the mark is selectable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. It is code intensive, but if anyone has this issue in the future and wants the details, I have a Stack Overflow question and answer on it here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36292623/3774582